# Can I use mods with the Xbox 360 version of Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I have a Mac and an Xbox 360. Is there a way to download mods on my computer, without downloading any software, and then put the mod onto a flash drive for my Xbox 360?

Comment: Hi John, welcome to Gaming.SE! While your main question is fine, your second request—asking for game saves—is off-topic here, and I've removed it.

Answer (score 4):

While there are ways to take your save from the Xbox 360 and edit it on your PC, (with something like [Modio](http://pinoytutorial.com/techtorial/how-to-mod-cheat-skyrim-xbox-360-via-pc-guide/), for example) there are no ways to download mods for Skyrim on your PC and have them run on the Xbox 360.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you have Horizon or something. Microsoft is strict about mods.

Comment: What exactly is Horizon? You've mentioned it, but haven't included any indication of what it is!

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I think he means this: https://www.wemod.com/horizon